# How to mock a 3rd-party library

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I am trying to write a rpsec for this class:

```
class SshConn
  def initialize(hostname, user, pass)
    @hostname = hostname
    @user = user
    @pass = pass
  end

  def ssh_connect(cmd)
    data = ""
    Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @user, :password => @pass) do |ssh|
      data = ssh.exec!(cmd)
      ssh.close
    end
    data
  end
end
```

I have the Net::SSH gem installed and I want to mock that library and test my class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no code showing your attempt to mock Net::SSH. Where are we to start helping you? At Mocking 101? We expect you to have researched and tried, and after having tried multiple times and failed, to *then* ask, showing us your attempts with explanations of why you think it isn't working. As is we have no idea where you are on the learning curve, which means writing a tutorial for the entire process, which is off-topic because it's too broad of a question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889200/testing-ssh-connection